# Discord.js TypeError: member.roles.filter is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to do a userinfo command, which says the user's roles, but returns this error. This is the code:

```
.addField(
  "**Cargos**",
  `${
    member.roles
      .filter(r => r.id !== message.guild.id)
      .map(roles => `\`${roles.name}\``)
      .join(" **|** ") || "Nenhum cargo"
  }`,
  true
);
```

Comment: Where does `member` come from? Is it a *Guild* or a *Message* member?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your question and tell us what error you're getting, and what you've tried to do to fix it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the cache, to get the roles.

```
  .addField(
      "**Cargos**",
      `${
        member.roles.cache
          .filter(r => r.id !== message.guild.id)
          .map(roles => `\`${roles.name}\``)
          .join(" **|** ") || "Nenhum cargo"
      }`,
      true
    );
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me so much.